# Error: You cannot define a correlation name 'type_shirt_idx' more than once

Tags: database, error, layered-navigation

I've been trying to find the culprit giving me this error message "You cannot define a correlation name 'type_shirt_idx' more than once"

Question: does anyone know what the error can be in layered navigation?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:68:"You cannot define a correlation name 'type_shirt_idx' more than once";i:1;s:3939:"0 /lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'type_shirt_idx....', Array, NULL)
1 /lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(336): Varien_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'type_shirt_idx....', Array, NULL)
2 /lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(315): Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'type_shirt_idx....', Array, NULL)
3 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(70): Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'type_shirt_idx....', Array)
4 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(94): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->applyFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute), '142')
5 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(91): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute->apply(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute))
6 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(73): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initFilter()
7 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(136): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->init()
8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
9 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')
11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')
12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
14 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
15 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
16 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
17 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
18 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
19 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
20 /app/Mage.php(705): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
21 /index.php(89): Mage::run('ml7_default', 'store')
22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:108:"/category/excellent-katoen-overhemd?occasion=184&shirt_size=12&shirt_weving=188&type_shirt=142";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:11:"ml7_default";}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because Magento tries to join the same filter with the same alias twice. Most common reason is you have 2 or more `catalog/layer_view` blocks at the page. Check the layout files and disable 3-d party extensions.