# You cannot define a correlation name 'link_attribute_qty_decimal' more than once

Tags: database, api, zend-framework

Have this problem for an API feed:

> You cannot define a correlation name 'link_attribute_qty_decimal' more than once at public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, Zend_Db_Select_Exception(code: 0): You cannot define a correlation name 'link_attribute_qty_decimal' more than once at public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php:833)"}

To me it seems like there is a product with quantity like 10.5 that does not have decimals used in the quantity. Have checked all product and made the changes. But still gets the error.

Anyone that can help me here will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to join the same attribute more than once.
Check this link it has already been explained [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53972/error-you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name-type-shirt-idx-more-than-once)

Comment: I'm looking for a hint to find out where the problem is.
Pretty sure it has nothing to do with block but more likely product quantity related.
Maybe there is a way in db to find out what the problem is.

Have cheched all products with quantity 10.5 etc and made decimal allowed for these products but the problem is still there.